# Error installing postgresql in windows server 2008 x64

Tags: windows-server-2008, postgresql-9.2

Im trying to install postgresql 9.2.4.1 in a windows 2008 server but always get this error at the end of the installation:

**initdb.exe error in application (0xc0000135)**

I try everything to make it work (complete disable the firewall, disable UAC, set permissions for postgres folders, check the user is an admin, etc)

Every time i try to reinstall i erase all old installation folders and postgres user using net user and start again...

I tried many other versions (9.3, 9.1, 8.4)and even 64 bits versions.... none work

Cheking the installation log, you can see at the end something about the server is not listening on 5432 port... but i just cant make it work..

The software i created is supposed to connect to the server database made in postgresql but it never work if i cant install it on the server...